# How to fix the issue about "waiting for all target devices to come online" in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I tried to run my android app but suddenly got the issue ""waiting for all target devices to come online" so it's take more time but anything didn't happen so please tell the solution for this issue

I added the screenshot of the issue

[image: Issue]

Comment: Are you using virtual device?

Comment: No, I'm using Emulator